# Clicking on a TTStyledTextLabel selects the UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ttstyledtextlabel

I have a `TTStyledTextLabel` inside a `UITableViewCell`. Clicking on the cell navigates to a new view controller, so I can't disable selection, but when I click the `TTStyledTextLabel`, the `UITableViewCell` is also selected. Any thoughts on clicking the TTStyledTextLabel without also selecting the table view cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subclass **TTStyledTextLabel** and override the following two methods:

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event

just like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
    point.x -= _contentInset.left;
    point.y -= _contentInset.top;

    TTStyledBoxFrame* frame = [_text hitTest:point];
    if (frame) {
        [self setHighlightedFrame:frame];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    TTTableView* tableView = (TTTableView*)[self ancestorOrSelfWithClass:[TTTableView class]];
    if (!tableView) {
        if (_highlightedNode) {
            // This is a dirty hack to decouple the UI from Style. TTOpenURL was originally within
            // the node implementation. One potential fix would be to provide some protocol for these
            // nodes to converse with.
            if ([_highlightedNode isKindOfClass:[TTStyledLinkNode class]]) {
                TTOpenURL([(TTStyledLinkNode*)_highlightedNode URL]);

            } else if ([_highlightedNode isKindOfClass:[TTStyledButtonNode class]]) {
                TTOpenURL([(TTStyledButtonNode*)_highlightedNode URL]);

            } else {
                [_highlightedNode performDefaultAction];
            }
            [self setHighlightedFrame:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, with few changes I was able to make it block only the touches over the links.